# How to change or set "Passenger Pool Idle Time"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, passenger

Error in my application passenger log.

```
[error]Premature end of script headers: 
[ pid=xxxxx thr=x file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:xxx time=2012-10-06 07:45:05.816 ]: The backend application (process 29746) did not send a valid HTTP response; 
instead, it sent nothing at all.
It is possible that it has crashed; 
please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
```

I searched on the internet and i found that this issue can resolve by setting the passenger pool idle time.

Can any one please suggest how to set it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Apache httpd.conf file add this line after "LoadModule passenger_module"

```
PassengerPoolIdleTime 300
```

Change the "300" to the number of seconds the application process can be idle before being shut down to conserve memory.

Comment: thanks, i have change it to 500 let's see that my application will shut down or not!

Comment: My server is again shut down today with same error. I think there is problem with active, inactive and count in PassengerPoolIdleTime. Can you please suggest how to and where to set it?

Comment: I am not really familiar with those Passenger options, but now that you know where to put them, you can see all the stuff you can play with in the Passenger documentation: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPoolIdleTime